# why alert() cannot give message as i expected?

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

javascript code:

```
    // JavaScript Document
function getInfo()
{
    var username,office,phone,food,amount,cost;

    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    office = document.getElementById("office").value;
    phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    food = document.getElementById("food").value;
    amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;


    switch(food){
        case "Sizzling Fry Jacks":
            cost = 100;break;
        case "Earthy Johnny Cake":
            cost = 70;break;
        case "Cut-o-Brute":
            cost = 50;break;
        case "Berlize Traditional Beer":
            cost = 30;break;
    }
    cost *= amount;


    alert("Username: "+username+"<br />"+"Office: "+office+"<br />"+"Phone: "+phone+"<br />"+"Food: "+food+"<br />"+"Amount: "+amount+"<br />"+"Total cost: "+cost+"<br /"+"Your food will arrive in 10 minutes!");
}
```

html code:

```
<a href="../index.html"><input type='button' value="SUBMIT" name="submit" id="submit" class="apply" onClick="getInfo()" /></a>
```

why browser doesn't give message of information?
i cannot find mistake of my js script...

many thx!

p.s.:don't mind the name of these foods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a mistake of mixing your data *into* your HTML.

If you keep the data in JavaScript and just use HTML to *show* the data, it will be a lot easier to use the data in calculations, modify it based on a user interaction, etc

Click <kbd>Run Code Snippet</kbd> below to see it work

```js
// keep your data in a reasonable data container
var foods = {
  "Sizzling Fry Jacks": 100,
  "Earthy Johnny Cake": 70,
  "Cut-o-Brute": 50,
  "Berlize Traditional Beer": 30,
};

// define the info fields
var infoFields = ["username", "office", "phone", "food", "amount"];

// this function just gets the value of the info fields
// and adds the dynamic field `cost`
function getInfo() {
  var info = infoFields.reduce(function(info, id){
    info[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;
    return info;
  }, {});
  info.cost = foods[info.food] * parseInt(info.amount, 10);
  return info;
}

// this function displays the info object with an alert
function displayInfo(info) {
  alert(Object.keys(info).map(function(field) {
    return field + ": " + info[field];
  }).join("\n"));
}

// now run it
var info = getInfo();
displayInfo(info);
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>Username <input id="username" value="Ness"></label>
<label>Office <input id="office" value="Onett"></label>
<label>Phone <input id="phone" value="1234567"></label>
<label>Food <input id="food" value="Cut-o-Brute"></label>
<label>Amount <input id="amount" value="6"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your switch statement. You don't have a default clause and it's expecting strings that need to match the case otherwise the cost calculation will fail.

try this:

```
switch(food){
        case "Sizzling Fry Jacks":
            cost = 100;break;
        case "Earthy Johnny Cake":
            cost = 70;break;
        case "Cut-o-Brute":
            cost = 50;break;
        case "Berlize Traditional Beer":
            cost = 30;break;
       default:
            cost = 1;
    }
```

Comment: i suppose that a switch statement without default clause is also vaild

Comment: it's valid but that's not the issue. The problem is that unless the variables EXACTLY MATCH the string, cost won't be set and the line where you do the math will error out.

Comment: oh i forgot to tell u,the form that used to select food is a drop - down menu

Answer (score 0):

***`Here is the code that prints the alert per your expectations`***

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
<head> 
 <title>Javascript Testing</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <pre> 
        Username  : <input type="text" id="username" name="username" /> <br>
        Office    : <input type="text" id="office" name="office" /><br>
        Phone     : <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /><br>
        Food      : <input type="text" id="food" name="food" /><br>
        Amount    : <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" /><br>
    </pre>

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="clickme();"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function clickme(){

var cost, amount, username, office, phone, food;

    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    office = document.getElementById("office").value;
    phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    food = document.getElementById("food").value;
    amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amount").value);

//Previous code
/*switch(food){
        case "Sizzling Fry Jacks" :
            cost = 100;
        break;
        case "Earthy Johnny Cake" :
            cost = 70;break;
        case "Cut-o-Brute" :
            cost = 50;break;
        case "Berlize Traditional Beer" :
            cost = 30;break;
    default : "This does not match"

    }
    cost *= amount;  */


//Edited code
switch(food){
        case "Sizzling Fry Jacks" :
            cost = 100;
        cost = amount * cost;
        console.log(cost);
        break;
        case "Earthy Johnny Cake" :
            cost = 70;
        cost = amount * cost;
        console.log(cost);
        break;
        case "Cut-o-Brute" :
            cost = 50;
        cost = amount * cost;
        console.log(cost);
        break;
        case "Berlize Traditional Beer" :
            cost = 30;
        cost = amount * cost;
        console.log(cost);
        break;
    default : 
        cost = 05;
        cost = amount * cost;
        console.log(cost);
        break;

    }

    alert("Username: "+username+"\n"+"Office: "+office+"\n"+"Phone: "+phone+"\n"+"Food: "+food+"\n"+"Amount: "+amount+"\n"+"Total cost: "+cost+"\n"+"Your food will 

arrive in 10 minutes!");;}

</script>
```

**Do let me know if you have any confusion.**

Comment: but the problem isn't on alert(), the script goes wrong since the getElement part, so the alert() wasn't run. so the type of amount doesn't cause the error

Comment: @Rundis - Is it that you want to see the final answer in alert box after the relevant computation in switch code section ?

Comment: something familiar, i want to give feedback of what user input as a confirmation, and calculate the cost. switch statement is used to get food that was chosen, for different food has different price. and  final output in alert box is product of amount and price

Comment: @Rundis - **Just check the edited code...** **`I hope this is what exactly you were looking out for`**

Comment: @Rundis - The reason why your code was not able to compute the final output previously, was due to the **`value of cost`** being **out of scope.**   Since you were calculating the cost outside of switch case, the code was not able to pass the cost in the total amount section.. **Hope you are now able to relate what I am trying to convey !!**